# MFC: Stop a thread from deleting the input pointer to its ControllingFunction

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have a thread defined as:

```
m_DoIt_Thread=AfxBeginThread(DoIt_ThreadProc, (LPVOID)this, 0, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED);
```

with DoIt_ThreadProcm defined as:

```
UINT CMyClass ::DoIt_ThreadProc(LPVOID pData)
{
    CMyClass * self = (CMyClass *)pData;
    self->DoIt();
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently pData is destroyed after the thread is finished. Is there a way to stop that so that the pointer is not destroyed? can we define/overwrite destructors for mfc threads?

This is branching off from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559749/maintain-access-to-variables-in-a-thread-after-it-finishes). Also I think there are also connections with this forum [post](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?211756-Thread-Parameter-delete-and-ClassDestructor-MFC).

Comment: Are you sure `this` in the first code snippet survives long enough? There's nothing that will destroy `pData` in your second (unless `DoIt` does), you're probably not looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pData` is *not* destroyed when the thread finishes. It is treated by the thread function as a pointer to void, which you can cast to anything you need/should to pass data to the thread. But the thread does not do anything with the memory `pData` points to nor with the object in this memory.

Actually the only thing it *could* do is freeing the memory (with `delete`), but that makes assumption that memory was allocated with `new`, and this assumption may be false. Luckily MFC does not make this assumption, and does not free the memory.

A destructor call would be completely impossible, because there is no information what object `pData` points to - it is `void*`. And no destructor is called. Your problem must be caused by something else.

Comment: I see, Good point. Just wondering now...Is the point of `m_bAutoDelete = false`, just to keep the pointer and the handle to the finished threads? In general, is there no concept similar to a deconstructor for a thread?

Comment: The `m_bAutoDelete` is member of `CWinThread` class, which is an MFC wrapper for threads. It controls the lifetime of `CWinThread` object, which has nothing to do with `pData`.

Comment: Yes I did in fact figure out the problem with my code. It was caused by the fact that the message pump was kept busy with the wait tasks so it couldn't respond. So this new question is related but not exactly associated to the question answered above.